Custom Router State data with NGXS
I have question about custom router develop with NGXS.
App Module
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyAccountComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    RegulationsComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterConfirmationPageComponent,
    CartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    NgxTranslateRoutesModule.forRoot({
      enableRouteTranslate: true
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsModule.forRoot([
      RouterState,
      AppState,
      CartState
    ], {
      developmentMode: !environment.production,
      selectorOptions: {injectContainerState: false}
    }),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsRouterPluginModule.forRoot(),
    SwiperModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MyAccountModule
  ],
  providers: [DatabaseService, AuthService, CartGuard, PricesGuard,
    {provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomRouterStateSerializer}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}

Custom Router State Serializer
export class CustomRouterStateSerializer implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateModel> {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateModel {
    const {
      url,
      root: {queryParams}
    } = routerState;

    let {root: route} = routerState;
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
    }

    const {params, data} = route;

    if (route.params.title) {
      data.title = route.params.title;
    }

    return {url, params, queryParams, data};
  }
}

Router State Model
export interface RouterStateModel {
  url: string;
  params: Params;
  queryParams: Params;
  data: any;
}

@State<RouterStateModel>({
  name: 'customRouter',
  defaults: {
    url: '',
    params: null,
    queryParams: null,
    data: null
  }
})
@Injectable()
export class RouterState {

  @Selector([RouterState])
  static state({state}: RouterStateOuterModel<RouterStateModel>) {
    return state;
  }

  @Selector([RouterState])
  static data({state}: RouterStateOuterModel<RouterStateModel>) {
    return state.data;
  }

  @Selector([RouterState])
  static params({state}: RouterStateOuterModel<RouterStateModel>) {
    return state.params;
  }

  @Selector([RouterState])
  static queryParams({state}: RouterStateOuterModel<RouterStateModel>) {
    return state.queryParams;
  }

  @Selector([RouterState])
  static url({state}: RouterStateOuterModel<RouterStateModel>) {
    return state.url;
  }
}

I prepared everything with documentation text but when I run my application, data doesn't appear in state. Object has initilazed but there is no data - nulls and empty strings.
I've tried dispatch custom router state in ngOnInit in app component, but nothing has changed.
In documentation is something that I didn't use:
NgxsRouterPluginModule.forRoot({ navigationActionTiming: NavigationActionTiming.PostActivation }), problem is that property navigationActionTiming doens't exist in NgxsRouterPluginModule.
How can I trigger custom router data and upadte when anything changed in main Angular's router?

In my configuration missed three things: router action - UpdatedRouterState, using it in router state as an actions and finally service which dispatch update action.
The last thing I had to do was to inject new service in app component's constructor.
Router Action:
import {RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router'
export class UpdateRouterState {
  static readonly type = '[Router] Update Router State'
  constructor(public payload: RouterStateSnapshot) {}
}

Router State:
@Action(UpdateRouterState)
  updateRouterState(ctx: StateContext<RouterStateModel>, action: UpdateRouterState) {
    const {url, root: {queryParams}} = action.payload;    

    let {root: route} = action.payload;
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
    }

    let {params, data} = route;

    if (route.params.title) {
      data.title = route.params.title;
    }

    ctx.patchState({url, params, queryParams, data});
  }

Router Service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { UpdateRouterState } from './router.actions';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouterFacade {
  constructor(private store: Store, private router: Router, private    activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const snapshot = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
        this.store.dispatch(new UpdateRouterState(snapshot));
      }
    });
  }
}

App Component:
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private store: Store,
          private routerService: RouterFacade) {

  }

